# Compact subset of $\mathbb Q$

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

Prove that any compact subset of $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$ has empty interior.

Note: I have seen this problem in some book. M.S. is not specified, which is very weird! 
If M.S. is $(\mathbb R,d)$ with $d=$usual metric definitely $\mathbb Q$ has empty interior, so we don't need the concept of compact spaces. I think the author means something else!

Comment: The author means the topologies on $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ generated by the usual metric. The interiors in question are the interiors in the spaces $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$, **not** in $\Bbb R$. Thus, $\Bbb Q\cap(0,1)$ not only has non-empty interior in $\Bbb Q$, it’s an open set in $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Ok, I understand! But can this be proved for (Q,d) ?

Comment: This can be relevant/duplicate/closely related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231509/what-do-compact-sets-look-like-in-the-rationals

Answer (score 6):

HINT: A subset of $\Bbb Q$ is compact in $\Bbb Q$ if and only if it is compact as a subset of $\Bbb R$, since compactness is an inherent property of the set and its relative topology, not of how it sits inside some other space. Thus, for $\Bbb Q$ you need only show that a subset of $\Bbb Q$ that is compact in $\Bbb R$ does not contain any set of the form $\Bbb Q\cap(a,b)$, since such sets form a base for the topology of $\Bbb Q$. Equivalently, show that if $A\subseteq\Bbb Q$, and $A\supseteq\big(\Bbb Q\cap(a,b)\big)$ for some $a,b\in\Bbb R$ with $a,b$, then $A$ is not compact.

The proof for $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ is similar; just substitute $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ for $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Sir, I'm very new to compactness! I want to ask you that why "a subset of Q that is compact in R does not contain any set of the form Q intersecting (a,b)"

Comment: @MAB: Remember that a closed subset of a compact set is always compact. Suppose that $A$ is a subset of $\Bbb Q$ that contains $\Bbb Q\cap(a,b)$, and suppose that $A$ is compact. There are irrational numbers $u,v\in(a,b)$ such that $u<v$; let $C=\Bbb Q\cap(u,v)=\Bbb Q\cap[u,v]$. Then $C$ is a closed (in $\Bbb Q$) subset of $A$, so $C$ is compact. But this is simply false: see if you can prove that such a set $C$ is **not** compact. HINT: A subset of $\Bbb R$ is compact if and only if it bounded and closed in $\Bbb R$; is $C$ closed in $\Bbb R$?

Comment: You have helped me understand that a compact subset $A$ of $\Bbb Q$ is bounded and closed in $\Bbb R$ and that because $A$ is closed in $\Bbb R$, set $A$ is nowhere dense in $\Bbb Q$. But does that characterize compact subsets of $\Bbb Q$? In other words, if a subset $A$ of $\Bbb Q$ is bounded and nowhere dense in $\Bbb Q$, is $A$ compact in $\Bbb Q$? I cannot figure out a proof nor think of a counterexample. I suspect the answer is "no" because the definition of a nowhere-dense set, which is that its closure has an empty interior, suggests that nowhere-dense sets are not necessarily closed.

Comment: @user0: Let $a$ be an irrational number, and let $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be a strictly increasing sequence of rational numbers converging to $a$. Then the set $A=\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is a bounded, nowhere dense subset of $\Bbb Q$ (and is even closed in $\Bbb Q$), but it is not compact.