# Proof: The subspace Q of rational numbers is not locally compact

Tags: general-topology

Several proofs of this statement are available on this site, however, I did not find mine anywhere which leads me to believe it could be wrong. I am hoping someone could review it for correctness. Thanks!

Take R with the usual topology and Q as a subspace.

We want to show Q is not locally compact.
Let x $\in$ Q.

Let U be some open set containing x, where U is open in R.

Then take V = { U $\bigcap$ Q }. Then V is open in Q and contains x.

(*) Note that V is an interval in Q as it is derived from an interval in R intersected with Q.

Suppose some compact subspace in Q contains V. Call this compact set B. Then B is also a subspace of R.

Then consider the following theorem:

> A subspace A of R$^n$ is compact if and only if it is closed and is bounded in the euclidean metric d or the square metric p. (Munkres Th. 27.3)

Then by the above B must be closed. But then B must contain all of its limit points.

By (*) we know V must be an interval in Q, hence B must at least contain some interval in Q. So that interval in Q can be written:

$I$ $\bigcap$ Q is some interval in the subspace Q, where I is an interval in R.

This interval in Q cannot be closed since any neighborhood around an irrational must intersect a rational number and there must be irrational numbers in the interval I. Hence irrational numbers are limit points of $I$ $\bigcap$ Q and hence it is not closed. By the above theorem $I$ $\bigcap$ Q is also not compact. So B cannot be compact.

Since B must contain some interval of the form $I$ $\bigcap$ Q, so a compact set containing V cannot exist. Hence Q is not locally compact at x and thus not locally compact in general.

EDIT: Looking for a response to my comment below. Thanks!

Comment: There are several inaccuracies. The most glaring is: "This interval in Q...there must be irrationals... in I". Since the interval is in Q it cannot contain any irrationals, but that does not mean it is not closed. A set is closed *in* a space, not in and of itself. So $[0,1]\cap Q$ is closed in Q even though it does not contain irrationals.

Comment: So I agree that [0,1] is closed in Q, however it is not closed in R as it does not contain all its limit points. The theorem we are using is concerned with whether the subspace is a closed set in R. Since any subspace B of Q is also a subspace of R, we need that subspace B to be closed within R. If B is shown to be compact in R then it must be compact using open sets in Q as well. Conversely if a set is to be compact in Q (under the subspace topology of R), then it must be compact in R. (both of these statements rely on how open sets in the subspace topology are defined) @Chrystomath

Comment: A set is *compact* in and of itself; it is an intrinsic property of the space (or subspace). "If $B$ is compact in R then it must be compact using open sets in Q as well". That is false. An open subset of Q (eg Q itself) need not be open in R, and you cannot use it in an open cover of R. Moreover, the compact subsets of Q are much more complicated than those of R. See this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231509/what-do-compact-sets-look-like-in-the-rationals.

Comment: “If B is compact in R then it must be compact using open sets in Q as well.” .... take any open coving of B with open sets in Q. Each of these open sets in the covering can be written as an open set in R intersect Q. Now the R open sets cover B in R and hence can be made finite since B is compact in R. Then take this finite subcollection and intersect each set with Q. Now u have a finite subcollection that covers B with open sets in Q.  —- where is my error here @Chrystomath ?

Comment: In your "proof", you make a false inference from "B is compact in Q" to "B has an interval in Q". The reasoning is not clear, but seems to involve an inference through "B has an interval in R". Explain.

Comment: The set B contains an interval in Q because it contains V which was constructed as the intersection of Q with an open interval in R. Does that help? @Chrystomath

Comment: You can clarify the whole argument. Your proof in a nutshell: Let $B$ be a compact set in $\mathbb{Q}$ containing a rational interval $V=I\cap\mathbb{Q}$. Then $B$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}$ (because compactness is intrinsic), so is closed in $\mathbb{R}$. But there are limit points of $V$ which are not in $B$, hence contradiction. There's nothing wrong with your proof, but you have to be more exact in your wording, especially when you say "closed" by itself without reference to $Q$ or $R$.