# Connectedness of one point compactification of $\mathbb Q$

Tags: general-topology, compactification

I have come across a question asking to prove/disprove that $\mathbb Q^+$, the one point compactification of $\mathbb Q$ endowed with subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb R$, is connected.

I think $\mathbb Q^+$ is connected.

$\mathbf {My Attempt.}$ Claim: Let $A,B$ be two nonempty open set in $\mathbb Q^+$ such that $\mathbb Q^+=A\cup B$, then $A\cap B \neq \emptyset$

Let $A,B$ be two nonempty open set in $\mathbb Q^+$ such that $\mathbb Q^+=A\cup B$. Without loss of generality, let $\infty\in A$. Then according to the definition of topology on $\mathbb Q^+$, $\mathbb Q^+ -A$ is closed and compact in $\mathbb Q$.
Since only compact spaces in $\mathbb Q$ endowed with subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb R$, is finite sets, thus $\mathbb Q^+ -A$ must be finite. Again any open set in $\mathbb Q^+$ is infinite. Hence $B$ is also infinite. Since  $\mathbb Q^+ -A$ is finite, thus $B$ must intersect $A$. Hence $A\cap B\neq\emptyset$.

So $\mathbb Q^+$ cannot have a separation. Hence $\mathbb Q^+$ is connected.

Am I right? Please give your suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: It's not true that only finite sets are compact in $\mathbb{Q}$. But a compact subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ must have empty interior.

Comment: Not all compact subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$ are finite (for example $\{1/n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\cup\{0\}$ is compact as a convergent sequence together with its limit point). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231509/what-do-compact-sets-look-like-in-the-rationals) for more info.

Comment: I would also remark, for simpletons like me who are reading the definition of "Alexandroff extension" on wikipedia, that the terminology is confusing in the following way:
Some authors seem to have in mind *Hausdorff compactifications* when they use the word "compactification". This confused me for several minutes, since of course $\mathbb{Q}^+$ is not Hausdorff.

Comment: Yes I got the point.  My way of approach is not correct. Please help me to prove or disprove this. I am unable to think of any alternate way.

Comment: It's not that your *approach* is incorrect, you just have a wrong assumption about compact sets in it. With the obvious modifications, your approach works if you can prove that a compact set in $\mathbb{Q}$ has empty interior. Do you see that? And to prove that a compact set in $\mathbb{Q}$ has empty interior, the hint at the end of Brian M. Scott's answer at the question Tyrone linked is helpful.

Comment: If possible let, A $\cap$ B = $\phi$ . Then B $\subseteq$ $Q^+$-A. Thus interior of B must be subset of interior of $Q^+$-A. Again, since $Q^+$-A is compact in Q, thus interior of $Q^+$-A is empty. Hence interior of B is empty - which is a contradiction to the fact that B is a nonempty open set in Q. Hence A and B are not disjoint. This shows $Q^+$ has no separation. Thus $Q^+$ is connected. ...... Is it correct now ?

Comment: It is correct if you have proved that compact subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$ have empty interior.

Comment: Yes, I have done that. Thanks to all. Thanks a lot.